# Do any scriptures mention which yoga asanas should be performed everyday?

Tags: vedas, yoga, yoga-sutras

Do Patanjali's yoga aphorisms or any other scriptures mention anything about which yoga asanas we should practice everyday?

Comment: Well, if you're a member of the first three castes, you're supposed to do Sandhyavandanam every day, and that involves various Asanas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan caste or varna?

Comment: I don't make any distinction between caste and Varna; caste is just the English translation of Varna.  In any case, Sandhyavandanam is the required daily duty of everyone who wears a sacred thread, and wearing the sacred thread is the duty of all Brahmanas, Kshatriyas, and Vaishyas; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2901/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, Nearest translation for *Varna* can be "Division", though not precise. Various "Caste" are just names given to certain group of people in various "Divisions". "Castes" can be hundreds, while *Varna*s are just 4. "Castes" can come and go, while *Varna*s would usually retain in a decent society. A "Caste" can associate with certain *Varna* at 1 time & another *Varna* at other time, or both. Analogy: "Man-Woman" is a division, while "Husband-Wife", "Father-Daughter", "Son-Mother" are castes. Some explanation on "Caste" vs "Division" http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9202/1049

Comment: @iammilind We just translate Sanskrit words differently.  I translate Varna as caste as Jati as sub-caste.  Each Jati falls under only one Varna; insofar as a Jati "associates" itself with different Varnas at different times, that's an indication that they were or are during something wrong.  In any case, our more fundamental disagreement is about our views on whether Varna is a birth-based system.  I think Varna is based on parentage (which is based on reincarnation) and it is unchangeable except in very rare circumstances (like Vishwamitra). But we'll have to agree to disagree on that.

Comment: @iammilind I agree with you. **Varna** literally means color. Like color says about physical appearance of something varna says about Guna or quality. in Kali Yuga, birth based caste and Guna based varnas are not in accordance. Many verses of Manusmriti and events ([Ekalavya's Guru Dakshina](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8181/3500)) looks "logical or rational only", when we apply Guna based Varna.

Comment: No they don't. Asanas are gymnastic exercises only. They are not taught in the Vedantic scriptures. They are recommended for beginners to help establish flexibility for sitting longer periods of time in meditation, but they are not recommended as a lifetime pursuit. You are spirit, not body. Too much emphasis on body will make you believe you are the body ...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, I feel what you wrote should be elaborated into an answer. At least it's agreeable to me. Here are my thoughts: There are many books & sessions promoted using term "Yoga" (mainly showing *Asana*). Actually they perform these exercises in disguise of Yoga. Even *PrAnAyAma*s are also breathing exercises. If a person sits with eyes closed in *tapas mudra*, thinking about daily matters, is still not Yoga. AFAIK, Yoga in its literal sense means addition with God, irrespective of means. Various exercises depicted as "Yoga" might be indeed Yoga for few, but not guaranteed for all.